# Having a problem proving subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $p_n(x)= x^n$ for $x$ in reals and if Possible $= \text{span}\{p_0,p_1,p_2,\ldots\}$ Then how do I show that $P$ is a subspace of all real valued continuous functions on Reals.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to notice that any linear combinarion of your $p_i$ is in fact a continuous function on Reals. Check it is also a vector space, so it is by definition a subspace of all continuous functions.

Comment: So it's the linear combination of 1,x,x^2,x^3....right....where is the zero function here... moreover I have a solution which says this is a subspace but not a vector space...I m really confused about this...

Comment: Oh, sorry then the statement was not correctly understood by me or clearly stated. A span are the linear combinations of functions with coefficients in a field. I supposed that the field was real numbers, and so you can take the linear combination with all coeficients equal to 0.

Comment: Ok thanx Rob...dat was something wat I was thinking...but then it should also be a vector space then